# vanillajs toggle checkbox off if one is unselected and on if all selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have currently developed a method to toggle all checkboxes on and off, as seen in the following.

I'm looking for something one step further, which fulfills the 2 conditions with vanilla js preferably.

1. If any of the checkboxes become unchecked (3 on the right in this case), select-all becomes unchecked as well.
2. If all checkboxes are checked (all 3 in this case), select-all automatically becomes checked.

I'm having some trouble figuring out what is the easiest way to do this (without some brute force), wondering what will be a good way of approaching this. Here is what I have currently. (1st box checks all)

```js
var checkAll = document.querySelector(`input[name=selectAllExistingDetails]`);
    checkAll.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Checkbox is checked
            // check all location checkboxes
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('existingLocationCheckboxDetails');
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        } else {
            // Checkbox is not checked
            // uncheck all location checkboxes
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('existingLocationCheckboxDetails');
            for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<label id="select-all-existing-details">Check All
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllExistingDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added function on other check boxes than select all.

if any of checkbox is unchecked, then select all will be unchecked,

else it will check if the length of all checked checkboxes is equals to the all checkboxes then it will check select all.

Also Shorten your code.

```
checkAll.onchange = function() {
  checkboxes.forEach(x => x.checked = this.checked);
};
```

```js
var checkAll = document.querySelector(`input[name=selectAllExistingDetails]`);
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=existingLocationCheckboxDetails]`);

checkAll.onchange = function() {
  checkboxes.forEach(x => x.checked = this.checked);
};


checkboxes.forEach(x => {
  x.onchange = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      var checkboxesChecked = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=existingLocationCheckboxDetails]:checked"); // Collects all checked/selected checkboxes.
      if (checkboxesChecked.length >= checkboxes.length) {
        checkAll.checked = true;
      }
    } else {
      checkAll.checked = false;
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<label id="select-all-existing-details">Check All
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllExistingDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're trying to accomplish. Let me know if this looks like it:

```js
const checkAll = document.querySelector(`input[name=selectAllExistingDetails]`);
const otherChecks = [...document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="checkbox"]:not([name=selectAllExistingDetails])`)];

document.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
  return;
 }
  const isAll = event.target === checkAll;
  const isChecked = event.target.checked;
  if (isAll) {
    otherChecks.forEach(c => c.checked = isChecked);
  } else {
    checkAll.checked = otherChecks.every(c => c.checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<label id="select-all-existing-details">Check All
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectAllExistingDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="existingLocationCheckboxDetails" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: white;">
</label>
```